# React Highcharts 'forExport' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am getting this error on loading the chart :
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'forExport' of undefined
a.Chart.destroy**
I'm dynamically rendering the data by parsing a JSON object. Is this a bug? Im stuck. Can someone help me fix this error?

Comment: You'll need to post your code or else no one will be able to see what the problem might be.

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: Looks like my formatter function for x-axis was creating this issue. Used toString() method, instead of directly changing (this.value).

Answer (score 0):

This is seen when you call on Highchart object when it is already been destroyed or Highchart object is not present.
Please refer this
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9232

```
function destroyChart() {
  if(this.highchart && this.highchart.destroy){
   this.highchart.destroy()
  }
}
```

Comment: Fixed it, some other function was creating this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This entry is historic but I have just found the same issue with highcharts.
A temporary fix is to set StrictMode off.
On my app it then works as it should.
I think this must be a bug and I have posted another stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73136371/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-forexport).