# React-HighCharts Uncaught TypeError: undefined 'forExport'

Tags: reactjs, react-highcharts

This is happening with React using react-highcharts but ONLY when StrictMode is on.
It seems that StrictMode is running through its first iteration then tries to destroy the graph that does not exist.

The failing line from highcharts.src.js, where chart is undefined, is:

```
        /**
         * Remove the chart and purge memory. This method is called internally
         * before adding a second chart into the same container, as well as on
         * window unload to prevent leaks.
         *
         * @sample highcharts/members/chart-destroy/
         *         Destroy the chart from a button
         * @sample stock/members/chart-destroy/
         *         Destroy with Highstock
         *
         * @function Highcharts.Chart#destroy
         *
         * @fires Highcharts.Chart#event:destroy
         */
        destroy: function () {
            var chart = this,
```

...

```
            // Delete the chart from charts lookup array
            if (chart.renderer.forExport) {
```

Turn off StrictMode and it works exactly as it should.
At no point am I manually disposing of the graph.
This does not seem like a long term solution.
Is there something I am missing? This seems like a bug to me.